# How to calculate an intersection of polyline and 3D surface?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

I want to calculate intersection points of polyline and a closed 3D surface (given as a set of polygons).

For simple 2D cases I can use `shapely`. Can you advice me something for 3D case?

P.S. My programming language is Python, but C++ libraries can be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider every line segment and every polygon independently and build their axis-aligned bounding boxes. Now for every pair of overlapping boxes, rotate the polygon  to the horizontal plane, and the segment accordingly, and find the piercing point of the supporting line of the segment.

Then check if the piercing point belongs to the segment and to the inside of the polygon.